how to pass multiple icon in AccordionToggle @strapi/design-system?
<Accordion expanded={expanded} onToggle={() => setExpanded(s => !s)} id="acc-4"> <AccordionToggle togglePosition="left" title="Add new stage" action={<IconButton onClick={() => console.log('edit')} label="Edit" icon={<Drag />} />} /> <AccordionContent> <Box paddingLeft={6} padding={5} background="white"> <Flex gap="10%"> <TextInput placeholder="Stage Name" required label="Stage Name" name="Stage Name" style={{ width: '500px'}}/> <SingleSelect label="Color" required  placeholder="Color"> <SingleSelectOption value="apple">Apple</SingleSelectOption> <SingleSelectOption value="avocado">Avocado</SingleSelectOption> <SingleSelectOption value="banana">Banana</SingleSelectOption> <SingleSelectOption value="kiwi">Kiwi</SingleSelectOption> <SingleSelectOption value="mango">Mango</SingleSelectOption> <SingleSelectOption value="orange">Orange</SingleSelectOption> <SingleSelectOption value="strawberry">Strawberry</SingleSelectOption> </SingleSelect> </Flex> </Box> </AccordionContent> </Accordion>
<AccordionToggle togglePosition="left" title="Add new stage" action={<IconButton onClick={() => console.log('edit')} label="Edit" icon={<Drag />} />} />
multiple icon in here with  and 
